# Assigned User Group selections unchecking themselves

Tags: joomla-3.x, user-groups

I can't for the life of me figure this one out. On a school site I built that's using Joomla 3.3/moodle/joomdle.

For some reason, and only on SOME users, their user level is getting unchecked and they lose access to the content or even the site. I've also had several admin users lose access as well.

has anyone ever seen this? School starts on Tuesday and we can't have students getting locked out of the site.

Comment: Such issues usually are caused by other extensions that manipulate users/usergroups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha, Just updated Jomsocial to 3.2.1.4 and the change log says:

"ACL of user randomly changes when using groups."

We'll see if that fixed it.

http://www.jomsocial.com/change-log/3214

Update: Yes, updating to this version fixed the issue.